Asus/Intel NUC 12th and 13th Gen: The System BIOS has detected an unsuccessful POST attempt - Watchdog
Finding with NUC12WSv5 and NUC13L3Hv5, with BIOSs v0087 to v0092 and v0043 respectively, when hot restarting, come up with a "The System BIOS has detected an unsuccessful POST attempt..." enter BIOS Y/N.
Downgrading BIOS on the NUC12s doesn't work. v0037 on the NUC13s seemed to be a little better, but the NUC13s only had this issue intermittently, where as the NUC12's it can be reproduced continuously.
Intel/Asus says the fix is to disable boot to network and/or reset BIOS to default. Boot to Network is disabled by default, and resetting to default settings doesn't improve the situation.

The fix is to disable the Watchdog in BIOS, then the unit will boot properly.
BIOS -> Advanced -> Onboard Devices -> Watchdog (Untick).
(Watchdog is enabled by default and can potentially be useful for 24/7 operation of different services, however between BIOS bugs and software bugs, the feature really doesn't do what Intel advertised it to do).
